# how to validate numbers in vuetify rules

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

i need to add number rules like numbers should be between `1 to 100` & `111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 999, 1000`

i have done making rules from 1 to 100

```
rules: {
        amount: v => {
          if (!v.trim()) return true;
          if (!isNaN(parseFloat(v)) && v >= 0 && v <= 100) return true;
          return "Number has to be between 0 and 100";
        }
      },
```

but how to validate 111 to 999 unique number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numbers you accept the factor of 111.

```
let num = 111;

if (num < 1000) {
  if (Number.isInteger(num / 111)) {
    console.log(true);
  } else {
    console.log(false)
  }
} else {
  // create the validation rules for the numbers that bigger than 999
}
```